# How do I construct a vector of objects that have constructor arguments?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to do something like:

```
class Circle {
    int radius;
    public:
        Circle( int r ) : radius(r) {}     
}

vector<Circle> circlesVector;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Circle circle(i);
    circlesVector.push_back(circle);
}
```

But this does not seem to work the way I want it to. The vector tries creating Circle objects using a constructor for Circle(Circle&) or some behavior that I don't understand or expect.

Comment: What error are you getting? Here it worked correctly... just had to add `;` after the class and create a `main` function for the `for`.

Comment: getting "error: no matching function call for call to 'Circle::Circle(const Circle&)"

Comment: Try posting some real code people can try to compile. i.e remove the spurious errors. Like in [this example](http://ideone.com/AJSut3).

Comment: To be storable in a vector at all, a type has to be move (or copy) constructible, to allow the vector to move elements into a new memory region when it needs to grow. The type you've posted is; presumably, your real type isn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you posted is fundamentally fine, bar a few typos and missing includes. You can see [this working demo](http://ideone.com/AJSut3).

But you don't need to create the temporary `Circle` object. You can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    circlesVector.push_back(i);
}
```

because `Circle` is implicitly constructable from `int`.
Note that you can also use an initializer list:

```
vector<Circle> circlesVector{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

alternatively, use `emplace_back`:

```
circlesVector.emplace_back(i);
```

Comment: Is there a real difference between `push_back()` and `emplace_back()` here?

Comment: what's emplace back? never seen it befor

Comment: @0x499602D2 Semantically, yes. No copies or moves are required with `emplace_back`.

Comment: According to C++ documentation, emplace_back() needs the T to be emplace constructable.

Answer (score 3):

Class Circle has a conversion constructor that converts an object of type int to an object of type Circle:

```
Circle( int r ) : radius(r) {}
```

So you can use this fact that to build the vector

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    circlesVector.push_back( i );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can take advantage of a convertion constructor which you have provided so `Circle` is implicitly constructible from `int`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    circlesVector.push_back(i);
}
```

will be just fine. However in case of many variables in constructor you can use i.e. `std::transform`:

```
Circle initC ( Circle c) {
    static int i = 0;
    return Circle(i++); // copy assignment operator
}                       // will be used to assign new Circle into default
                        // version of Circle present already in vector
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Circle> cVec(10);
    std::transform( cVec.begin(), cVec.end(),
                    cVec.begin(), initC);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get away with doing it all in the constructor by creating a temporary vector of radiuses:

[Example](http://ideone.com/eRpyta):

```
class Circle 
{
private:
    int radius;
public:
        Circle( int r ) : radius(r) {}     

        int GetRadius() const { return radius; }
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> radii(10); // vector to hold your radiuses
    std::iota(radii.begin(), radii.end(), 0); // initialize them to the desired sizes
    std::vector<Circle> circles(radii.begin(), radii.end()); // use your conversion constructor
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Circle[" << i << "] radius = " << circles[i].GetRadius() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"The vector tries creating Circle objects using a constructor for Circle(Circle&) or some behavior that I don't understand or expect.". STL containers (at least with C++98) copy construct objects you add to them.

Comment: The copy constructor is the default copy constructor as he did not define one.  Unless he is using an insanely old compiler, this should not be an issue.

Comment: Exactly. I wanted to explain why it should be expected the copy ctor is called